# How to use parentheses for generics?

Tags: templates, generics, call, rust, lifetime

I'm getting the compile error:

angle-bracket notation is not stable when used with the `Fn` family of traits, use parentheses [E0215]

What does this mean?  How do I "use parentheses"?

```
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MemoedFun<A, R> {
    fun: fn(&A) -> R,
    map: HashMap<A, R>,
}

fn memoize<A: Eq + Hash, R>(fun: fn(&A) -> R) -> MemoedFun<A, R> {
    MemoedFun {
        fun: fun,
        map: HashMap::new(),
    }
}

impl<'a, A, R> FnOnce<A> for &'a MemoedFun<A, R> {
    type Output=&'a R;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First of all, you cannot use `Fn*` traits directly in stable Rust. This includes 1) using angle-brackets notation, and 2) implementing these traits. It is possible to enable a feature flag for both of these things in unstable Rust though.

Second, if you do use angle brackets for closure traits, you have to use tuples for arguments, even if there is only one argument:

```
FnOnce<(A,)>
```

Third, the error message is that instead of `FnOnce<(T, U), Output=V>` you should write `FnOnce(T, U) -> V`. That's what is meant under "using parentheses" message. I agree that this message is misleading here because you can't implement `Fn` when it is written like this because of associated types. I guess the error about implementing `Fn` types should take precedence over this error.

Fourth, you won't be able to do what you want (a memoizing function backed by a hash map) when you use `&'a MemoedFun<A, R>` because you need a mutable pointer to update the map. You need to implement `FnOnce` for `&'a mut MemoedFun<A, R>`:

```
impl<'a, A: Eq + Hash, R> FnOnce<(A,)> for &'a mut MemoedFun<A, R> {
    type Output = &'a R;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (arg,): (A,)) -> &'a R {
        if self.map.contains_key(&arg) {
            &self.map[&arg]
        } else {
            let r = (self.fun)(&arg);
            self.map.entry(arg).or_insert(r)
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the resulting code you would have to write to use this memoizer isn't pretty. You can't use function syntax on your "function" for some reason, so you would need to use `call_once()` directly:

```
fn computer(x: &i32) -> i32 {
    println!("Computing for {}", x);
    -*x
}

let mut f = memoize(computer);

println!("f(10): {}", (&mut f).call_once((10,)));
println!("f(10): {}", (&mut f).call_once((10,)));
println!("f(42): {}", (&mut f).call_once((42,)));
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=df3ab940742a120f06cf&version=nightly))

There is a reason why `Fn*` traits manual implementation is not stabilized, after all.

Comment: Is there a rust bug for this misleading error message? I couldn't find anything by a naive search,

Comment: I haven't found one either, so I guess it makes sense to create one.

Comment: What does FnOnce(T, U) -> V mean?  I can't find a description of this syntax.  Is Output a special keyword?

Comment: Oh, I see now.  You're not actually using FnOnce(T,U) -> V in the place I thought you were.  That's just the type of the resulting function.

Comment: @dspyz, `FnOnce(T, U) -> V` is a syntax for closure trait bounds, it is described in the book in the [chapter on closures](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html). `Output` in `FnOnce<(T, U), Output=V>` is a syntax for specifying associated types in trait bounds, and it is also described [in the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html).